# How to make an HTML link to an image that forces the image to download the image?

Tags: download, url

I want to make a downloadable url from an image.

Let's say that we have

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg
```

When you open it, the browser only shows the content on the webpage, as it should.

Instead, I want to, when you click on that link, it automatically downloads the image, is there anything to be changed to achieve this?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas please check my edit

Comment: Nice!  Much better! :)  The browser itself controls this behavior based on its mime type so if you are ONLY referring to the image.. then no; however, Please see [this page](https://community.adobe.com/t5/dreamweaver/force-image-link-to-download-instead-of-opening-in-new-tab/td-p/9833884?page=1) about the same topic.  Look down toward the bottom about .htaccess files.. I *think/hope* it might be what you are looking for.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE, JULY 22, 2023**: In 2023, yes you can with the `download` attribute with modern browsers.

Simply add the `download` attribute to the  tag like this:

```
<a href="/images/myimage.jpg" download>
```

And the file will be downloaded instead of being displayed inline.

*Older answer below for transparency and reference.*

---

No.

JPEG images will always be displayed in the web browser.

Sorry to say but web browsers are designed from day one to display certain image and file types. As such, a direct link to an HTML URL for an image will always display the image on the page.

That said, if you are building your own website and wish images to be downloaded, one thing you can do is GZip the source image itself and link to it.

GZipped files are compressed archives and will always be downloaded and — in many cases — the default behavior for a compressed archive that is downloaded via a web browser is to decompress that file on a successful download.

Comment: @1NN Corrected. New browsers do new things!

Comment: New Browsers? The "slow adopter" Safari supports this since version 10.1 in 2017 [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) - but good you corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Use the download attribute of the anchor tag.

```
<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg" download>download image</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download